# GitHub Action | Trigger pipeline for root folder except one sub folder

Tags: github-actions

I wanted to trigger the pipeline when any file is changed in the directory or subdirectories of folder `/ProjectA/` except `/ProjectA/sub-dir-a`.

I added the below event to achieve the results, however, it throws an error saying Path and Path-ignore cannot be added in the same event.

```
    on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths: "ProjectA/**"
    paths-ignore: " ProjectA/sub-dir-a /**"
```

**Error Received**
[image]

Further, If I change an event to include "paths" only, it triggers the pipeline even when any files are changed in the subfolder too.

I was looking for an option to exclude sub directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see you cannot mix the `paths` with `paths-ignore` but if you look at the [filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) and later at the [pattern to match file paths](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#patterns-to-match-file-paths) section you can see you can also negate patterns:

> Using an exclamation mark (`!`) in front of a pattern negates it. When a file matches a pattern and also matches a negative pattern defined later in the file, the file will not be included.

Having that in mind you can try with:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths: 
      - "ProjectA/**"
      - "!ProjectA/sub-dir-a/**"
```

### EDIT

[The example from the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-and-excluding-branches) covers exactly your case.

Comment: `- "!Project/subdir/sub-dir-a/**"` will match e.g. `ProjectX\file.txt`, so this doesn't solve OP's problem if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hi @riqq, it will not match the `ProjectX/**` as the directory is not included into `paths`. The first pattern (`ProjectA/**`) does not include it. The two patterns in `paths` mean: _Inlcude (only) files from `ProjectA` directory except all the files from a `ProjectA/sub-dir-a` directory_.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry. The example here should cover OP's case exactly: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-positive-and-negative-patterns-1

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to do for a Github Action while building a Docker CI/CD pipeline. I wanted to avoid docker builds for README files (not a sub-folder as asked in the OP) so this is what I did

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "java/**"
      - "!**/README.md"
  pull_request:
    branches:
        - main
```

This worked like a charm.